# Create DLL in C++ and using in C# with BSTR* return function

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I'm meeting the problem when creating DLL in C++ and using in C# with an array of String.
 Here is my DLL code in c++, Im creating info.dll

```
extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) BSTR* GetInfos()
{
string result1 = "ABC", result2="DEF";`
BSTR* MyBstr = new BSTR[2];
MyBstr[0] = SysAllocString(CA2W(result1.c_str()));
MyBstr[1] = SysAllocString(CA2W(result2.c_str()));
return MyBstr;

}
}
```

In c# code, Im creating DLL import to get this Function in class getInfoFromDll:

```
    [DllImport("info.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = false)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    static extern string[] GetInfos();
```

I can't get any results when call GetInfos() from my DLL.

```
 String[] s = getInfoFromDll.GetInfos();
```

Comment: *How* doesn't it work? What problems do you have? Doesn't one of the components build? Do you get runtime errors (crashes)? Unexpected results? Something else?

Comment: I mean I can't get any results when call GetInfos() from my DLL. In this case, I can't get GetInfos()[0] are "ABC" String and GetInfos()[1] are "DEF" String.

Comment: The C# declaration says that a BSTR should be returned, but you are returing a *pointer* to a BSTR...

Comment: I think this is a way to declare an array of string in C++ and I can use in C#, Do u know  an other way to create an array of String in C++ dll and using in C#?

Comment: The pinvoke marshaller cannot possibly find out how many strings are in the array.  Nor can it release the memory for the array.  This cannot work, you need a SAFEARRAY instead.